# Post processing Wicket response (Rhino, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wicket, rhino

My question is if there is a way to simply post process wicket HTML response?

What I want to do is to apply some DOM transformations to the generated HTML using Rhino (http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) and jQuery.
Anyone ever thought about it? Any suggestions where to start?

Best,
Maciej Wrzalik

---

OK, I've got this:

```
public class MyRequestCycle extends WebRequestCycle {
    public MyRequestCycle(WebApplication application, WebRequest request, WebResponse response) {
        super(application, request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEndRequest() {
        String responseString = response.toString();
        //String newResponseString = process(responseString);
        //replace old response content with the newResponseString 
        super.onEndRequest();
    }
}
```

In method **onEndRequest** the string **responseString** contains HTML code that I'm going to alter some way using Rhino, Envjs and jQuery but the question is how can I replace the old response content with the new one?

Answer (score 1):

Envjs emulates the browser environment under Rhino, and specifically allows you to do DOM manipulation server-side using jQuery. I have used it before in my projects, and have had good success. Relevant resources:

- http://www.envjs.com/
- http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/

Answer (score 1):

If you want the post-processing done on the server, your best bet is likely to implement a [Servlet Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) which modifies the response before it goes to the client.

As you're working on the rendered HTML, this has nothing particular to do with Wicket, and could be applied to html generated by any Java framework.

Answer (score 1):

[As suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386742/post-processing-wicket-response-rhino-jquery/4387286#4387286), a normal Java EE filter would work fine, if there's nothing Wicket-specific that you need for the processing.

But if you want to do it inside Wicket, for some reason or other, I suppose you could create your own RequestCycle implementation (`MyRequestCycle extends WebRequestCycle`) and do the processing there (perhaps by overriding onEndRequest and/or getWebResponse).

To use a custom RequestCycle, override newRequestCycle in your Application class:

```
@Override
public RequestCycle newRequestCycle(Request request, Response response) {
    return new MyRequestCycle(this, (WebRequest) request, response);
}
```

I'm using custom a RequestCycle for a couple of things (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3914528/56285)) myself—it's simple and straightforward—but I'm not 100% sure if it fits your needs here. (My Wicket experience is still somewhat limited.)